# Azure File Share -- mapping from on-Premises server Windows server to Azure File Storage

Tags: azure, azure-files

I have an on-premises Windows Server and Azure File Storage.

From my Windows Server, I want to use "Map network drive" to map the Azure file storage folder to a drive letter.

There is an 'Express route' between my company's intranet and Azure.

I know how to do this within Azure Windows VM. I am struggling to get mapping done from on-Prem server.

Comment: You want to map on-premise fileshare to Azure VM?

Comment: No. It's the other way around. I want to map on-premise Windows server to Azure File Share

Comment: `map on-premise Windows server to Azure File Share`? I don't mean it. Azure File share only provides smdb service, you could not map files  to it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to ensure that you have port 445 opened for the SMB protocol to work. This is easier in Azure VM but tough to get approval from any corporate IT security team. If you are through with this, [this post on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) gives you required details.

Comment: Thank you Hemant. A follow-up question.. How does on-premise server resolve the dns name  \\<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net\<share-name> ?